# Learning Python the Hard Way: Example 5

Tags: python

The following gives a syntax error:

```
my eyes = 'Brown' my_hair = 'Brown'
print "Hes got %s and %s hair" % (my_eyes, my_hair)
```

The only way this seems to work is if I put `Brown, Brown` in the last parenthesis.

Comment: Plus you can't have white space in variable name

Comment: And there's a ' and a eyes missing (but that's English not Python)

Comment: change `my eyes` to `my_eyes` and put `my_hair = ...` on a separate line!

Comment: This is why I hate "Learning Python the Hard Way" so much: It makes people mindlessly type in code without understanding what they are doing.  It *even says so* in this [very exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex5.html): *"As usual, just type this in even if you do not understand it and make it exactly the same."*

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly assigning, you should try to unpack the tuple of strings into two variables. In addition, Python variables can not contain spaces so you'll want to use an underscore for eyes.

```
my_eyes, my_hair = 'Brown', 'Brown' # unpacking tuple here
```

Also, I suggest you use the format method which is more common. That style is deprecated.

```
print "He's got {0} and {1} hair".format(my_eyes, my_hair)
```

Comment: without any comment, yes! OP seems utterly lost so perhaps explicitly state that WS in variable names are forbidden instead of silently giving the correct solution... BTW I didn't downvote :-)

Comment: Thanksfor your answer: But this does not work either:

Comment: name = 'Elizabeth R. Apodaca'
age = 57   #probably A LIE
height = 64 #inches
weight = 135 # lbs
eyes = 'Brown'
teeth = 'white'
hair = 'Brown'

print "Lets talk about %s."% name
print "She's %d inches tall." % height
print "He's %d pounds heavy." % weight
print "Actually, that is too heavy."
print "She's got {0} eyes and {1} hair". .format(eyes, hair)
print "His teeth are usually %s depending on the coffee." % teeth

print "If I add %d, %d and %d I get %d" % (age, height, weight, age + height + weight)

Comment: I tried the ,format before also and got the same result. Unpacking the tuples on the print line fared no better.

Comment: What I reall don't understand is why this code works for him.

Comment: Please paste your current code in the question so that I can determine your problem. Please stop repeating the fact that you are confused in the comments.

Comment: If you look at the 4th  comment above - The code is there. I do not believe I said I was confused - you did. I said I could not get it to work no matter what I did - except putting (Brown, Brown) in the tuple on the print line. I am not an idiot and would appreciate if you did not attempt to treat me as such.

Comment: No one called you an idiot... Don't treat us as such either... (Especially my friend over here that is only trying to help). This is a great answer. You didn't bother putting in the effort to resolve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the period at the end of the print statement was outside of the parenthesis. This now works: % (eyes, hair). The format version also works now.

Comment: I don't see a period in your posting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your variables:

```
name = "some name"
Age = 57
Height = 64
Weight = 135
Eyes = "brown"
Teeth = "white"
Hair = "brown"
```

To print a string with variables, use `str.format`.

```
print "Let's talk about {}".format(name)
print "She's {} inches tall".format(Height)
```

... So on

Make sure that your variables contain no spaces. They're case sensitive too :)